# How to automount usb external hardisks in ubuntu server 12.04?

Tags: server, hard-drive, automount

How can I automount USB HDs ? I installed usbmount but seems not working. Here below a few details:

sudo fdisk -lu:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 20.4 GB, 20416757760 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2482 cylinders, total 39876480 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000859fe

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    38238207    19118080   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        38240254    39874559      817153    5  Extended
/dev/sda5        38240256    39874559      817152   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0000d617

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048   972597247   486297600   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2       972599294   976771071     2085889    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5       972599296   976771071     2085888   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdc: 40.0 GB, 40020664320 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 4865 cylinders, total 78165360 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x43ba43ba

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *          63    78140159    39070048+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdd: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000c85ff

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1              63  1953520064   976760001    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sde: 1500.3 GB, 1500301910016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 182401 cylinders, total 2930277168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x48686a76

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sde1              63  2930272064  1465136001    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

sudo blkid:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="70d2b83a-1b0a-4c5d-b6ff-89d187b4c96a" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="444db037-76b9-4a53-b357-ab5ae1764044" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="500GB" UUID="7c0f92c4-3428-4e0a-b724-abe13229224c" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb5: UUID="370e0ecf-3190-4fe8-92d3-13cb1fedecb1" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="admin_only" UUID="528b53ef-15ac-4a2d-ad97-425af3a61995" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="Hitachi" UUID="e7f30f9f-2d42-4222-bce3-4b58d65c26e3" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext3" 
/dev/sde1: LABEL="Toshiba" UUID="5c61d0bd-eb41-4a8e-aa4e-b6db05d1b43e" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext3"
```

mount:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://superuser.com/questions/53978/ubuntu-automatically-mount-external-drives-to-media-label-on-boot-without-a-u

Answer (score 1):

When an USB devices is plugged in it gets probed. If you have a modern Linux distributen then the udev rules get triggered. (See `/etc/udev/rules.d` & `/lib/udev/rules.d`).

You can use those rules to run a script. That script can then read the drives label and take a specific action based on that (e.g. if the label is 'backup_drive_1` then rsync /data to that drive).

However: I have not tried that myself. All I have atm is an interest into how to do that and a few handy links. (in my case the goal was to resync a mdadm mirror to an specific USB drive).

Regardless, these links may set you on the right path, and maybe someone will post a ready made answer.

- http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#external-run
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5623/what-happens-when-a-usb-drive-is-plugged-in
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=168221
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469243/how-can-i-listen-for-usb-device-inserted-events-in-linux-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to add them to /etc/fstab

```
UUID=your-uuid-goes-here /where-to-mount-goes-here      ext4    defaults        0       2
```

NTFS example:

```
UUID=your-uuid-goes-here /where-to-mount-goes-here  ntfs-3g defaults,auto,umask=000,users,rw 0
```